# How can I find out the language of a selection in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I’m porting an extension I made for Sublime Text to VSCode. In Sublime Text, a document could use multiple programming languages. For instance, a PHP would have sections in HTML; an HTML file would have sections in JavaScript. I was not able to find in VSCode’s documentation how to do this using its API, and not even if this is indeed possible. The best I could do was to get the language of the whole document:

```
vscode.window.activeTextEditor?.document.languageId
```

Is there a way to get the information that what I want?

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Code doesn't determine the language for you, you have to find it out yourself. The language id is something set by an extension that is registered for a specific file type.

You can do the same and register your own extension, which then has to parse the input on every change and find language boundaries. You will have to maintain a main language (from which you derive the languageId) and keep boundaries of the embedded code parts somewhere yourself.

I'm not sure if the HTML extension handles embedded languages (could well be), but it certainly does not give out the found boundaries to other extensions.